# Как определить к какой базе подключен скрипт MySql или MariaDB

Tags: mysql, python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

Ситуация такая, есть скрипт, скрипт на python, который работает на нескольких серваках.
на одних установлен MySql на других MariaDB.

нужно из скрипта определить к какой базе подключен скрипт.

как это можно сделать?
взможно запросом.

в идеале с использованием sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через команду `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

На mysql она даёт такой результат:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.13                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1           |
| version                 | 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

А на mariadb следующий:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                            |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.29-76.2                      |
| protocol_version        | 10                               |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                  |
| version                 | 10.0.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
| version_comment         | Ubuntu 16.04                     |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                           |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu                 |
| version_malloc_library  | bundled jemalloc                 |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Соответственно разница в том, что в поле `version` есть вхождение `MariaDB`.

Через sqlalchemy можно выполнить raw запрос примерно следующим образом:

```
result = db.engine.execute("<ваш sql>")
```